# Not able to dump data to sql file

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to take backup of a table as sql file in postgres with below command.. the command is not executing properly.. can some one help ?

pg_dump -U postgres-a test_1 > test_1_dump.sql

Comment: What error is being shown in console after you enter your command?

Comment: The listed command does not seem to leave a space before `-a`, in which case pg_dump will interpret `postgres-a` as the user.

Comment: I dont get any error on executing the command..                                                Sorry Leo that was a copy paste error.. I have given space before -a in my command.